# REDCap stop logic if specific conditions are met

Tags: logic, branch, survey, redcap

I am wondering if in REDCap, I can enable stop logic to end a survey if certain conditions are met in two different fields.

For example, if a survey asks about ice cream flavors, and the survey respondent chooses:

What is your favorite brand of ice cream?
Ben and Jerry's

And then,
"What flavor do you choose?"
Phish Food --> which then would prompt stop logic to end the survey. Whereas if they responded "Half Baked", it would allow the user to continue to other questions.

Is this possible? I've thought that I can manipulate the forms that the respondent sees via the form display logic, but I figured that there has to be an easier way